# How can i Set Extra attribute in Laravel Collective Select

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I want to add an extra attribute in select option with laravel collectives using data-attribute.

my data:

```
array:8 [
    "id" => 3       
    "fee_head_title" => "ADMISSION FEE"
    "fee_head_amount" => 5000
  ]
```

i want to display like this with laravel collective select:

```
<select>
    <option value="{{$array->id}}" data-amount="{{$array->fee_head_amount}}">                
     {{$array->title}}</option>
</select>
```

laravel collective select template:

```
{!! Form::select('fee_head[]', $fee_heads, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

Comment: i guess you can't achieve with `Form::select(` so better to use only for this normal **HTML**

Comment: hey try this way http://thewebfosters.com/adding-custom-attributes-select-field-laravelcollective-html/